# Google places API - 'REQUEST_DENIED' when using server-side proxy on EC2

Tags: proxy, google-places-api, api-key

I'm stuck trying to get an API call to Google Places working.  I'm using a server-side PHP proxy for the request - not because I want to, but because it's part of [JQuery-POI-Mapper](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-poi-mapper/292342).

The server I'm using is an Amazon EC2 server without a static IP address. I'm out of stactic IP addresses at the moment, but I'll take the time to request more if people think that's the problem. I identified the current public IP address of my EC2 server by running this command on the server:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

Next, I went to https://code.google.com/apis/console and created a new API key.  I selected a server-side API key and used my EC2 server's public IP address.

---

[image]

---

Under the services tab, I enabled every related API I could think of, including:

- Google Maps API v2
- Google Maps API v3
- Google Maps Gelolocation API
- Places API
- Static Maps API

Here's a screen capture of my Services:

[image]

The proxy code running on the EC2 server is part of a commercial package, so I shouldn't post the entire code, but it's very short, and the important part is:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
```

The $url variable in my case was:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-37.7133771,145.14891620000003&radius=2000&types=bakery&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCCUV...
```

The response I get is:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I checked to see if I had gone over my quota already, but everything looks OK.  What's interesting is that Google is showing that I had made requests to the Places API today, so Google definitely knows that the requests are coming from me.

Here's a screen capture of my API Traffic Report, which is all from testing:

[image]

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Bret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Static IP address to successfully use IP Locking with a Server API Key.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I'll get one and see if it work.  If it does, I'll accept your answer. :-)

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks again.  That was indeed the issue.  Interesting note, though, that after I got an elastic IP address from Amazon and associated it with my EC2 server, I couldn't use the IP address to access the site.  If I tried to do that, the google maps wouldn't show up at all.  I needed to use the public DNS instead, then everything started working.  (Of course, I had to change my registered IP address in the Google API Access screen as well.)  Cheers!